# Test PHP script load on Debian server

Tags: mysql, php, debian, performance, load-testing

Anyone maybe know is there Linux (debian) tool for testing PHP application performance? I want to check in witch places my PHP/MySQL script need optimization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to profile your scripts and tweak performance under test conditions, have a look at [xdebug](http://devzone.zend.com/article/2899).

For HTTP optimization, you could do a lot worse than [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel).

However that does not replace the need to tune the application as a whole - if you've got a script taking 30 seconds to complete which only gets run once a month - then its less of a priority then one which takes 5 seconds and is fired of 1000 times per hour.

AFAIK there's no free off-the-shelf solution - I added %D to my apache logs and use some custom code around that to identify problems areas (prioritized based on product of frequency and duration for each URL). I also use a modified version of [this mysql log parser](http://www.retards.org/projects/mysql/) for my SQL code.

I'm currently in the process of evaluating [Yahoo Boomerang](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/06/performance_testing_with_boomerang/) and [graphite](http://codeascraft.etsy.com/2011/02/15/measure-anything-measure-everything/) for capturing large volumes of performance data.

There are commercial offerings - but

- PHP support is limited
- they are usually very expensive.

Comment: xhprof (available in pecl) is a great addition to the tools you named, here is a tutorial on how to use it (the documentation is scarce). http://techportal.ibuildings.com/2009/12/01/profiling-with-xhprof/


  [1]: http://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof

Comment: For MySQL, unless the author of the code is an experienced DBA, just running EXPLAIN will probably help quite a bit. Check the Slow Query Log, and go from there.

Comment: @Shadok: nice one